# How do I attach a 1.25in OD mast to a utility pole?

Tags: mounting, brackets, pole

I'm looking to install an antenna mast along a utility-type pole. [This bracket](https://www.lightingsupply.com/garvin-sob-1.aspx?msclkid=4b626ca35774109eff4e0e003c0bba30&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=All%20Products%20Shopping%20May%2021%202020&utm_term=4581046486295883&utm_content=Ad%20group%20%231) would be perfect, however, the mast I am mounting is 1.25in OD.

Comment: That looks like more of a stand off bracket, to hold things away.  You want a mounting bracket to hold the mast to the pole, at least on the bottom.  Those brackets you linked to seem to have some adjustment for sizes( the bolt tightens to hold.  The mast might move up or down with just using them.

Comment: That type of clamp is lagged onto a pole,,, however unless you own the pole on your property and no utilities on the pole you can not connect to it. There are different sizes out there what are the specs on that one.

Comment: Utility pole, get permission first (unlikely) or rue the day. Utility-*type* pole, many options depending what you are trying to do with the mast (Stick up further? Stick out? Run parallel to?) The power conduit on my utility pole, as installed by the utility, is through-bolted brackets (holes run right through the pole) for example. Takes a mean drill, but they had one. If you just need to stick up more, drill through the mast and use lag bolts through the mast into the pole if not up to drilling right through it for machine bolts, washer, lock-washers and nuts.

Comment: The used second hand poles have the holes already in them.  Might be lucky if they are in the right place.

Comment: On pole fittings, talk to an electrical supply house. Once I saw a Square D subpanel attached to the side of a house up very high. The wires looked *weird* so I asked.  Turns out this was a ham radio operator, the riser pipe coming up out of the box fed an antenna, and they used a subpanel *solely so they could use the top hub fitting to attach to their pipe*, thanks to commodity pricing it's the cheapest thing to do that job.  No AC power in there at all.

Comment: Two questions: What utility is the pole for. 2- is it yours ? 3- what type antenna ? satellite dish ?